# g++ complaining about STD functions

Tags: c++, g++, std

I have a section of downloaded source code, when trying to compile via Cygwin using g++ compiler, the compiler gives me an error saying that the 'transform' function is undeclared in this scope...

I am using the std namespace, and I have the correct headers. I am not sure why it is not compiling.. The syntax looks correct

Here is the code block section.

```
string tolower (const string & s)
  {
    string d = s;
    transform(d.begin(), d.end(), d.begin(), (int(*)(int)) tolower);
    return d;
  }  // end of tolower
```

Here is my header section:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// standard library includes ...

#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ios>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;
```

Comment: Sorry, but -1 *"and I have the correct headers"* No, clearly you don't

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the appropriate header for [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
#include <algorithm>
```

You should also avoid `using namespace std;` in the global namespace in headers, you pollute the global namespace of any code that includes your header file.

See [this post about `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?rq=1).

Comment: that ought to do it. Thank you.

Comment: re "You should also void using namespace std; in headers", I would restrict that advice to the global namespace in headers, and anyway there's no evidence that the OP is doing that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf How is there no evidence? The last line in OP's code is `using namespace std;`…

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf check the last line of the question.

Comment: i mean, there's no evidence that that is a header file.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Agreed about the global namespace. I interpreted "header section" to mean header file, but you're right, it is not unambiguous.